# See two frames in Photoshop at once

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I have a gif with several frames in Photoshop.  I used to use Fireworks for this and it would let me select more than one frame and one frame would appear on top of the other.

Is there anyway to do this in Photoshop?  I know I can use guides to align things but to have the previous frame visible at the same time would really help me see how the keyframe is progressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a free plugin called [AnimDessin Plugin](https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/1524#.VqJmTlIk5X8) available through the Adobe Add-Ons that will help you with all of this. Better frame control and onion skinning.